# How to turn on high-legibility alternates for system font in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, fonts, typography

I would like to activate high-legibility alternate style set for San Francisco font in UITextView, using Swift 3.1.

---

[image: example of high-legibility alternates]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for activating high-legibility alternates in UITextView.

```
// TextViewController.swift

import UIKit

class TextViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    // MARK: - View Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureTextView()
    }

    // MARK: - Configuration

    func configureTextView() {

        // Activate high-legibility alternates for system font.
        let systemFontDescriptor = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17).fontDescriptor
        let highLegibilityFontDescriptor = systemFontDescriptor.addingAttributes(
            [
                UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute:
                [
                    [
                        UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kStylisticAlternativesType,
                        UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kStylisticAltSixOnSelector,
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        )
        textView.font = UIFont(descriptor: highLegibilityFontDescriptor, size: 17)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was shown in [WWDC 2016 Session 803: Typography and Fonts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/803/) on slide 189.

Comment: @robmayoff That is where I found the example for activate high-legibility alternates. The rest of the code for TextViewController is from [UIKit Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code on Apple Developer website.

Comment: The WWDC video isn't available anymore ‍ but the slides may be found here ⟹ https://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2016/803_typography_and_fonts.pdf 